# Why the report not updating in POWER BI?

Tags: powerbi, diagram

Dashboard in Power BI was built based on the postgresql database. When it updating locally - all data in the dashboard is updated, but when placing it in production and setting an update schedule, after the expected update the following error is displayed:

> Status Several errors occur during data refresh. Please try again later or contact your administrator

`SessionID: 35e5304a-6b12-4cdf-b1fb-8c123456993d

[0] -1055784932: Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.. Key = [Schema = "bi_reports", Item = "bi_example"]. Table = #table({"Name", "Data", "Schema", "Item", "Kind"}, {}). ;The key didn't match any rows in the table.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

[1] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.

[2] -1055129594: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.`

I tried to re-place the dash, but it didn't help

Comment: Seems there is a difference between local and production. Are both reports using the same database & tables? Looks like you have a navigation step in PowerQuery on an item, and that item no longer exists.